# How to setup STM32f103c8T Bluepill + Platformio + UART the right way?

Tags: stm32, uart, platformio, bluepill

I've been trying to figure out how to upload a code to a STM32103c8T bulepill board.
My setup is

1- MacOs Catalina
2- STM32103c8T bulepill board
3- SLAB UART USB-TTL CP2012 V3.0
4- Platformio IDE
5- STM32 CUBE Programmer software which detects and connects to my board through UART.
meaning that It has no problem connecting but there are issue with setting up the Platformio

BTW I am new to the ARM world and I bought this board to examine its speed and deep sleep and interrupt, I mean all the things that an Arduino Uno can't do.

The thing is I have no idea on how to setup the platformio.ini File to comunicate with the board
using the UART method and not requesting ST-link dongle!

What I have now in **Platformio.ini** is:

[env:bluepill_f103c8]

```
platform = ststm32
board = bluepill_f103c8
framework = arduino
upload_protocol = stlink
upload_port = tty.slab_usbtoUART
```

and when trying to upload the program i get:

Uploading .pio/build/bluepill_f103c8/firmware.elf
xPack OpenOCD, x86_64 Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00378-ge5be992df (2020-06-26-12:31)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html

debug_level: 1

hla_swd

none separate

Error: open failed

in procedure 'program'

OpenOCD init failed

shutdown command invoked

[upload] Error 1

I just need help getting the system talk to each-other and see each-other

P.S.
**I want to go as bareMetal as possible and not to use arduino firmware HAL**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following configurations:

```
upload_protocol = serial
upload_port = COMX/ttyx //whichever applies
```

Comment: That works for genericSTM32F103C8 board. According to the documentation bluepill_f103c8 board doesn't have that upload protocol.